# Not able to append the json data

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, mongodb

Am trying to execute mongo query and mysql query, both results validating and returning into the variable. 
My issue is that it is returning mysql data only. not appending to mongo db results. if i place console.log then it is displaying but in return its not. please let me know where am missing in below code.

```
   var message= {'msg':gloabl_vars.messages.success,'mysql':{'msg':'success','data':[]},'mongo':{'msg':'success','data':[]}}; 
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
      var url=gloabl_vars.mongodb_data.url;  
      MongoClient.connect(url,function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;
        var dbo=db.db("profilemanager");       
        dbo.collection('userinfo').find({_id:userdata.msisdn},{'_id':0,'subscriptions':1}).toArray(function(err,result){
          if(err) throw err;
          var dumpdata=result[0].subscriptions;         
          for(var i=0;i<dumpdata.length;i++){
            var dump=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dumpdata[i]));     
            console.log(dump.state); console.log(dump.reqChrgCode); 
            console.log(dump.cCode);           
            if(dump.state==1 && dump.reqChrgCode==userdata.code && dump.cCode==userdata.service_code){
              message.mongo.data['mongodb_userinfo']='Mongodb details updated.';
              message.mongo.msg="Success";
              message.msg="Success";
            }
            else{            
              message.mongo.msg="Failed";
              message.msg="Failed";
              message.mongo.data['mongodb_userinfo']='Failed to update data in mongodb.'; 
            }
          }     
        });
      });

    sql.query(db_queries, params, function(
          err,
          results
        ) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
          } else {  
            var success_count=0;
            var running_count=0;
            for(let i=0;i<queries.length;i++){
              var temp=results[i]; 
              if(temp.length > 0){ 
                message.mysql.data[i] = {"info" :queries[i],"msg":"Success"};                    
                success_count++;
                running_count++;
              }
              else {
                message.mysql.data[i] = {"info" :queries[i],"msg":"Failed"};    
                success_count--;
                running_count++;
              }           
              if(success_count==(queries.length-1)) {
                message.mysql.msg="Success";
              } 
              else if(running_count==(queries.length-1)){
                message.msg="Failed";
                message.mysql.msg="Failed";          
              }           
            }
            result(null, message);
          }      
        });
```

expected output:

```
{
    "message": {
        "msg": "Failed",
        "mysql": {
            "msg": "Failed",
            "data": [
                {
                    "info": "SELECT * FROM imidigitaltrans_logs.gw_api_trans_log where gtrid=?;",
                    "msg": "Failed"
                },
            ]
        },
        "mongo": {
            "msg": "success",
            "data": [
                "userinfo":"Updated"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

actual:

```
{
    "message": {
        "msg": "Failed",
        "mysql": {
            "msg": "Failed",
            "data": [
                {
                    "info": "SELECT * FROM imidigitaltrans_logs.gw_api_trans_log where gtrid=?;",
                    "msg": "Failed"
                },
            ]
        },
        "mongo": {
            "msg": "success",
            "data": []
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have stored values in array is incorrect.

Change

```
message.mongo.data['mongodb_userinfo']='Mongodb details updated.';
```

To

```
message.mongo.data[i] = {'mongodb_userinfo': 'Mongodb details updated.'};
```

Same goes for your `ELSE` condition too.